# How to share api response between multiple Angular Components?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am trying to wrap my head around & use `BehaviourSubject` in Angular (so far without much luck). My goal is to share the api request response across my components.

Here's a stackblitz setup of what my project looks like:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-3cql7e?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapicaller.service.ts

In the console/network tab, there's currently three requests being made to the api.

How can I work with these so that only one api request is used for `component1` and `component2`

---

For a visual overview of this problem, here's a quick diagram:

```
                +-------------------+                              
                |                   |                              
                | apicaller.service | (api being called here)      
                |                   |                              
                +-------------------+                              
                                                                   
          +----------+      +-------------+                        
          |component1|      |component2   |                        
          +----------+      +-------------+                        
                  Use only 1 api call                              
                  to get data across                               
                  x amount of components
```

Comment: you can store response in a service variable,before calling the api just check response is there or not,if not then call the service otherwise not

Comment: even you can store it to `localStorage` if you want to maintain the state

Comment: You could but that doesn't sound like reactive approach you're supposed to be leveraging when using rxjs.

Comment: Does it matter if component2 is a child of component1? I´m trying a very similar scenario like the one above but in my case I have a parent and child component that uses the same service. Maybe the child component should stop using the service and instead depend on data being sent from the parent in my case?

Comment: Have a look at a library I wrote called ez-state. It is a glorified behavior subject designed to take the boiler plate out of creating Angular services to deal with rest endpoints. https://adrianbrand.medium.com/angular-state-management-using-services-built-with-ez-state-9b23f16fb5ae

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have wrong code in the method `getData()` in your service - it returns every time a new http request instead of sharing one. Just add another observable property in the service to solve this problem. Add inside pipe `shareReplay()` to make this observable hot after first subscription and then it will share the data. Like this:

```
private readonly request: Observable<Array<Object>> = this._http
  .get('https://swapi.dev/api/people/')
  .pipe(
    map((result: Object) => result['results']), 
    shareReplay(),
  );

getData(): Observable<Array<Object>> {
  console.log(Math.random() * 100 + ' getData()');
  // count api request
  // return as array of objects
  return this.request;
}
```

Comment: Still appears to be making two requests: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bs7jsp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapicaller.service.ts

Comment: Its only once. Check it again.

Comment: Stackblitz was showing a second ```fetch``` request+response. But worked alright in my local setup. Cheers

Comment: Be aware of the parameters of shareReplay. How often do you want to repeat the replay? During the complete application lifecycle (browser refresh)? Or maybe a finite amount of times OR time?

Comment: Also this answer doesn't use your preferred BehaviorSubject which might be fine, but just to mention. AND the StackBlitz example and also this answer are TypeScript without using Types! (edited answer).